# Add to cart button from controller layout cause redirect to controller url

Tags: magento2, layout, addtocart

I've got controller that render products in .phtml with add to cart button and return it via layout to ajax. When i hit the add to cart button this makes redirect to controller page. I need to reload current page or add the product via aja. btw i know why this happen, but don't how to fix this. any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this file 
`vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php` (where product is added to cart), magento calls

```
return $this->goBack($url);
```

which checks whether this request is ajax or not. If its ajax, it sends back a JSON instead of redirecting to a page.

see:

```
protected function goBack($backUrl = null, $product = null)
{
    if (!$this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
        return parent::_goBack($backUrl);
    }

    $result = [];

    if ($backUrl || $backUrl = $this->getBackUrl()) {
        $result['backUrl'] = $backUrl;
    } else {
        if ($product && !$product->getIsSalable()) {
            $result['product'] = [
                'statusText' => __('Out of stock')
            ];
        }
    }

    $this->getResponse()->representJson(
        $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data::class)->jsonEncode($result)
    );
}
```

Basically you need to pass 'ajax=true' in your add to cart request.

Hope this helps somehow.

Comment: Thanks for join, but i found another solution by passing current url to ajax and creating custom url generation. Anyway - thank you!